# Jsoup throwing NullPointerException on Connection.get() in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup for one of my android applications, and I have a relatively simple piece of code that keeps throwing NullPointerException when I call connection.get().

This used to work a couple months back, but after installing the latest SDK it no longer works in the emulator. It is working fine on my physical device, but I don't know if this is an emulation only bug or could impact other handsets.

This is my code:

```
String URL = "http://finance.google.com/finance/feeds/default/portfolios?returns=true"
String _AUTHPARAMS = "GoogleLogin auth="
String AuthToken = "random string of characters"

Connection c = Jsoup.connect(URL);
c.header("Authorization", _AUTHPARAMS + AuthToken);
c.userAgent("foo");
c.timeout(10000);
c.ignoreContentType(true);
Document doc = c.get();
```

I am catching a NullPointerException on the last line (c.get())

If I call exception.getMessage(), it just says "null". I'm not sure what else could be causing this other than a bug in android or jsoup?

======= EDIT ========

I'm using Jsoup 1.6.1

Here's the stack trace from eclipse:

```
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.readln(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1279)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl$ChunkedInputStream.readChunkSize(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:404)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl$ChunkedInputStream.<init>(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:340)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getContentStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1175)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.doRequestInternal(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1754)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.doRequest(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1649)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1374)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:381)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:364)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:143)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:132)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.karwosts.PortfolioMap.GoogleFinance.SendHttpRequest(GoogleFinance.java:138)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.karwosts.PortfolioMap.GoogleFinance.getDocument(GoogleFinance.java:78)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.karwosts.PortfolioMap.GoogleFinance.GetPortfolioList(GoogleFinance.java:36)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.karwosts.PortfolioMap.GooglePortfolioSelector$AsyncPortfolioRetriever.doInBackground(GooglePortfolioSelector.java:134)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.karwosts.PortfolioMap.GooglePortfolioSelector$AsyncPortfolioRetriever.doInBackground(GooglePortfolioSelector.java:1)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-01 00:43:22.459: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  ... 4 more
```

Comment: Attach the stack trace & version of JSoup you are using?

Comment: @Jens Information added to post, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your stack trace I'm guessing you're encountering this [bug (15554)](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15554) on an Android 2.1 (or other "old" version) - you should be able to download the document using the Apache HTTP client - which works a lot better on older Android implementations (since `HttpURLConnection` is/was a buggy piece of shit).

Comment: Not sure if its the same bug (mine's on 2.2 on wired ethernet connection), but I took your advice anyway and replaced with Apache HttpClient and it seems to work. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Well, Google [recommends HttpURLConnection](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) for 3.0 and later, but it's kind of buggy on 2.x versions.