# getResponseCode throws NPE

Tags: java, android

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

try {
  int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
```

Last line, exactly method `getResponseCode` throws NPE:

```
04-22 15:59:28.704: E/sreda(1627): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 15:59:28.704: E/sreda(1627):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.readln(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1279)
04-22 15:59:28.704: E/sreda(1627):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl$ChunkedInputStream.readChunkSize(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:404)
04-22 15:59:28.704: E/sreda(1627):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl$ChunkedInputStream.<init>(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:340)
04-22 15:59:28.704: E/sreda(1627):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getContentStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1175)
04-22 15:59:28.704: E/sreda(1627):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.doRequestInternal(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1754)
04-22 15:59:28.704: E/sreda(1627):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.doRequest(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1649)
04-22 15:59:28.704: E/sreda(1627):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1374)
04-22 15:59:28.704: E/sreda(1627):  at my.pack.service.DataService.get(DataService.java:184)
04-22 15:59:28.704: E/sreda(1627):  at my.pack.service.DataService.getWithRefresh(DataService.java:148)
04-22 15:59:28.704: E/sreda(1627):  at my.pack.service.DataService.getRemoteContacts(DataService.java:355)
04-22 15:59:28.704: E/sreda(1627):  at my.pack.activity.ContactsActivity$3.doInBackground(ContactsActivity.java:247)
04-22 15:59:28.704: E/sreda(1627):  at my.pack.activity.ContactsActivity$3.doInBackground(ContactsActivity.java:1)
04-22 15:59:28.704: E/sreda(1627):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
04-22 15:59:28.704: E/sreda(1627):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-22 15:59:28.704: E/sreda(1627):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-22 15:59:28.704: E/sreda(1627):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
04-22 15:59:28.704: E/sreda(1627):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
04-22 15:59:28.704: E/sreda(1627):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

UPD on Android 4.0 nothing exceptions, yet on Android 2.2

Comment: Because `urlConnection` is null.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Nope. Otherwise the exception would be earlier on. Read the stack-trace - the NPE is within the method indicated.

Comment: @DuncanJones You're right, my mistake.

Comment: on Android 4.0 nothing exceptions, yet only on Android 2.2

Comment: Do you have underscores in your url? Try it without underscores.

Comment: only in GET parameter - "access_token"

Comment: just for test: remove it

Comment: didn't help and I just rewrite with HttpClient

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into the same problem as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512849/jsoup-throwing-nullpointerexception-on-connection-get-in-android-emulator), in which a similar stack trace appears... Long story short: for old android versions, you're safer using Apache HttpClient.