# Is there a workaround for when HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode throws NullPointerException?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I'm getting a lot of errors caused by the error already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512849/jsoup-throwing-nullpointerexception-on-connection-get-in-android-emulator). Basically it happens on android 2.3 or below, when you call getResponseCode of a HttpURLConnection, what is weird is that this happens randomly (one of the causes is when you use underscores on the url, but I have seen this work even with these on the url).

I know the first recommendation would be to use the Apache library, but I found that i.e. the facebook SDK for android uses this too, and it breaks too frequently. I debugged this, so on facebook it's breaking on line 301 of class com.facebook.Response:

```
if (connection.getResponseCode() >= 400) { //a NullPointerExceptions is thrown here.
```

What is the recommendation to do here? I don't think a feasible approach would be to migrate the facebook part to use the Apache library, or if this is something that it can't be avoided and just ignore the error and let the user retry, which would be really bad, not sure how other apps resolve this.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure connection isn't null?

You can always catch NullPointerException and treat the entire attempt to download as a failure and retry/giveup.

Comment: Yeah pretty sure, while debugging I can see the connection properties filled, i.e. the url used. Thanks